# C issue, blur filter not working properly

Tags: c, loops, copy, computer-science, blur

Got a problem with code in C, the purpose is to blur given image working as a filter. The code reads height and width from `RGBTRIPLE` **bmp.h** file, makes a copy of each pixel in advance to compute the average in the middle pixel (when its 3x3 pixels chunk) or the boundary pixel's average (when its 2x3 chunk). I nested `for`-loops, 2 outer ones to copy each pixel from 'image', defined there 4 integers (3 doubles, 1 int.) to count each pixel's red, green and blue. The last int. is named counter to be my denominator in division.
The problem occurs not in syntax, but on the image. 4 down rows of pixels are like rainbow, each is different, not blurred. And the image is darkened.

When I don't use the pixels' copy it seems to work fine.

```
// Blur image
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    RGBTRIPLE copy[height][width];
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            // make a copy of rgbtriple image
            copy[i][j].rgbtRed = image[i][j].rgbtRed;
            copy[i][j].rgbtGreen = image[i][j].rgbtGreen;
            copy[i][j].rgbtBlue = image[i][j].rgbtBlue;

            // i need to ensure that image's pixels wont be out of bounds of rows/columns
            // it's inappropriate to have static division by 9 because sometimes there will be less pixels to divide by

            double sumRed = 0;
            double sumGreen = 0;
            double sumBlue = 0;
            int count = 0;

            for (int ii = i - 1; ii <= i + 1; ii++)
            {
                for (int jj = j - 1; jj <= j + 1; jj++)
                {
                    if (ii >= 0 && ii < height && jj >= 0 && jj < width)
                    {
                        sumRed += copy[ii][jj].rgbtRed;
                        sumGreen += copy[ii][jj].rgbtGreen;
                        sumBlue += copy[ii][jj].rgbtBlue;
                        count++;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (count != 0 && count <= 9)
            {
                image[i][j].rgbtRed = round(sumRed / count);
                image[i][j].rgbtGreen = round(sumGreen / count);
                image[i][j].rgbtBlue = round(sumBlue / count);
            }
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to copy the *entire* image before you begin the blur operation. You are reading from the copy of neighbour pixels that have not been initialised.

Comment: It means I should create for-loop specified for copying?

Comment: Yep. `for(int i = 0; i < height; i++) for(int j = 0; j < width; j++) copy[i][j] = image[i][j];` and remove the copying that you already have.

Answer (score 0):

You compute the new value of the `image` pixels from the data in the `copy` matrix, but you did not copy the whole image before hand, only pixel values up to the current pixel. Hence the results are incorrect.

You should copy the whole image in a separate loop or using `memcpy`.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <string.h>

// Blur image
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width]) {
    RGBTRIPLE copy[height][width];
    // make a copy of rgbtriple image
#if 1 // using memcpy
    memcpy(copy, image, sizeof(copy));
#else
    // if you cannot use memcpy
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
            copy[i][j] = image[i][j];
        }
    }
#endif
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
            // Mix the color values with the adjacent pixels
            // making sure the pixels are inside the image.
            // It is inappropriate to always divide by 9
            // because depending on the pixel position and image size
            // count can be 1, 2, 3, 4, 6 or 9
            double sumRed = 0;
            double sumGreen = 0;
            double sumBlue = 0;
            int count = 0;

            for (int ii = i - 1; ii <= i + 1; ii++) {
                for (int jj = j - 1; jj <= j + 1; jj++) {
                    if (ii >= 0 && ii < height && jj >= 0 && jj < width) {
                        sumRed   += copy[ii][jj].rgbtRed;
                        sumGreen += copy[ii][jj].rgbtGreen;
                        sumBlue  += copy[ii][jj].rgbtBlue;
                        count++;
                    }
                }
            }
            // no need to test count: there is at least one pixel
            image[i][j].rgbtRed   = round(sumRed   / count);
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen = round(sumGreen / count);
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue  = round(sumBlue  / count);
        }
    }
}
```