# CS50 PS4 filter-less blur

Tags: c, cs50

I'm having issues getting my code to return correct values and I can't stare at it anymore or my eyeballs will fall out.

Specifically, the test I've failed are
-blur correctly filters middle pixel
-blur correctly filters pixel on edge
-blur correctly filters 3x3 image
-blur correctly filters 4x4 image

```
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) // Go through rows
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) // Go through columns
        {
            // Reset counters
            float totalblue = 0.0; // Total of values
            float totalgreen = 0.0; // Total of values
            float totalred = 0.0; // Total of values
            int counter = 0;

            for (int k = -1; k < 2; k++) // To make 3x3 square
            {
                for (int l = -1; l < 2; l++) // To make 3x3 square
                {
                    if (i + k >= 0 && i + k < height && j + l >= 0 && j + j < width) // Determine if pixel exists
                    {
                        // Update totals
                        totalblue += image[i+k][j+l].rgbtBlue;
                        totalgreen += image[i+k][j+l].rgbtGreen;
                        totalred += image[i+k][j+l].rgbtRed;

                        counter++;
                    }
                }
            }

            // Set new values
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue = round(totalblue / counter);
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen = round(totalgreen / counter);
            image[i][j].rgbtRed = round(totalred / counter);

        }

    }

    return;

}
```

I've tried playing with the data type (but that doesn't seem to be the issue) and reworking the parameters for determining whether a pixel exists. It seems like that test is what's giving me the problem? Or an issue with my counting?

Comment: `&& j + l >= 0 && j + j < width)` Too many `j`s, not enough `els`... Use slightly longer and more meaningful variable names so they stand out... Even `ii` instead of `k` and `jj` instead of `l` (that looks too much like a `1`)

Comment: You need to make another array that matches the image and blur the source image into that new array then copy it back to the source at the end. If you don't then the pixels you've blurred in the source are used in the next calculation, etc.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/75346917/2410359

Comment: @RetiredNinja - Thank you! I made a new array and it worked. What you explained makes perfect sense, too.